# Tree project structure in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, project-structure

I don't like the non-tree structure that eclipse provides me with (dot separators instead branches). Is there some plugin that would make it look more net beans or visual studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I think you meant packages and classes organisation.

Go to "View Menu" (Ctrl-F10), Package Presentation and change it from flat to Hierarchical

Answer (score 2):

Click on the small white triangle at the top-right of the package explorer view (View Menu), then choose "Package Presentation - Hierarchical".

Comment: thanks, that's what I needed, and you were first, however "hotkey guy" wins :)